# forkJoin() delay between API calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
return forkJoin(
          pages.map(
            i => this.http.get(`devices?page=${i}&size=8000`)
          )
        ).subscribe((event: any) => {
          event.forEach((entry) => {
            devices = devices.concat(entry.content);
          });
```

The problem with this code is that it sends a burst of API calls to my server in case the number of pages it has to fetch is high.

I have tried to add a small delay to each API call with the following code:

```
i => this.http.get(`devices?page=${i}&size=8000`).pipe(delay(1000))
```

but no luck - it still sending all API calls in a burst, I assume this is the behavior of forkJoin().

Any idea if there is any simple approach for sending a request one after one, contacting the result of all of them to one array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would examine the possibility to use `mergeMap` instead of `forkJoin` to controll the level of concurrency your server is ready to sustain.

The code would look like this

```
concLevel = 10 // set the concurrency level

return from(pages) // generate a stream of pages out of the array
.pipe(
  // transform the source into a stream of responses to http requests with a controlled level of concurrency
  mergeMap(page => this.http.get(`devices?page=${page}&size=8000`), concLevel),
  // accumulate all events into an array which is returned when the source Observable completes
  toArray()  
)
.subscribe((event: any) => {
  event.forEach((entry) => {
    devices = devices.concat(entry.content);
});
```

I do not have a playground to test this, so there may be some errors, but I hope the idea is clear

Answer (score 3):

[contactMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap#map-values-to-inner-observable-subscribe-and-emit-in-order) : Map values to inner observable, subscribe and emit in order.

```
   from(pages).pipe(
            concatMap( i=> this.http.get(`devices?page=${i}&size=8000`))
        ).subscribe ( event => {
                    event.forEach((entry) => {
                devices = devices.concat(entry.content);
              });
        });
```

Comment: No need to add `delay` in case of `concatMap` as it makes sure that next request will be processed once previous one is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` operator instead as it executes observables at alternate intervals.

See documentation for reference: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip

```js
// RxJS v6+
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, zip } from 'rxjs';

const sourceOne = of('Hello');
const sourceTwo = of('World!');
const sourceThree = of('Goodbye');
const sourceFour = of('World!');
//wait until all observables have emitted a value then emit all as an array
const example = zip(
  sourceOne,
  sourceTwo.pipe(delay(1000)),
  sourceThree.pipe(delay(2000)),
  sourceFour.pipe(delay(3000))
);
//output: ["Hello", "World!", "Goodbye", "World!"]
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```